# Handler in addValueEventListener running continuously

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im making a Uber clone app and whenever the driver receives a request he can accept it or decline it, but I want to add a feature where if the driver doesn't accept or decline the request within 8 second I want to decline it automatically.

Let me explain my code, I'm creating a `DatabaseReference checkJobRequest` that will point to the current `driverId` and I'm actively listening if a child called `dataSnapshot.hasChild("jobRequest")` appears, if it does appear that means there is a request for the driver so I'm going to create another listener and check the status of that request `String valueOfStatus = (String) snapshot.child("requestStatus").getValue();` now if the status is "waiting" I'm going to display a dialog where I ask the driver to accept it or decline it.

Now the problem is when I try to implement a handler that is going to decline the request automatically after 8 seconds, the handler never stops running because its inside the `checkJobRequest.addValueEventListener`, and this listener is always running in the background checking for a request. I tried killing the handler `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` but since the listener runs again and again it will start it again and again like a loop.

can someone suggest a workaround this problem?

```
private void jobRequest(){
    // clicked=false;
    String driverId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference checkJobRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverId);
    checkJobRequest.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("jobRequest") && !isCurrentlyWorking){
                DatabaseReference checkStatusValue =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverId).child("jobRequest");
                checkStatusValue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.hasChild("requestStatus")) {
                            String valueOfStatus = (String) snapshot.child("requestStatus").getValue();
                            String waiting = "waiting";

                            if (valueOfStatus.equals(waiting))
                                mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            else mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                mRideAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        clicked = true;
                        isCurrentlyWorking = true;
                        String driverId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        checkJobRequest.child("jobRequest").child("requestStatus").setValue("accepted");
                        DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverId);
                        driverRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.hasChild("customerRequest"))
                                getAssignedCustomer();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });


                    }
                });
                mRideDecline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        isCurrentlyWorking = false;
                        clicked=true;
                        mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        checkJobRequest.child("jobRequest").child("requestStatus").setValue("declined");

                    }
                });


                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            //isCurrentlyWorking = false;
                           // clicked=true;
                            mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            checkJobRequest.child("jobRequest").child("requestStatus").setValue("declined");
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);


            }else mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: leaving `onCancelled` with nothing in it is a bad idea, at least log the errors or better yet, do proper error handling for it

Comment: @a_local_nobody okay I will handle that later

Comment: @ADM
 u r changing a node and you also listening for changes this might trigger a recursion .. No this is not the problem the code works fine it doesn't trigger a recursion, and yes you are right I will decouple the code later, now I'm just trying to do a proof of concept

Comment: What's the problem with the shared code? Any errors?

Comment: Alex Mamo
yes its activating the Handler again and again whenever the addValueEventListener runs